# How to save html5 canvas as an image file in window 8 metro app?

Tags: javascript, canvas, windows-8, microsoft-metro

```
var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

I think `myImage` has the image bytes encoded in png format
now how to save `myImage` as a file (in images folder)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `.toDataUrl`, you need to use `.msToBlob`:

```
var blob = canvas.msToBlob();
```

Then, you'll need to write this out to disk:

```
var output;
var input;
var outputStream;

Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync("yourFile", 
          Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).
    then(function(file) {
        return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
    }).then(function(stream) {
        outputStream = stream;
        output = stream.getOutputStreamAt(0);
        input = blob.msDetachStream();
        return Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.copyAsync(input, output);
    }).then(function() {
        return output.flushAsync();
    }).done(function() {
        input.close();
        output.close();
        outputStream.close();
    });
```

In your applications app data folder, you will now have the image written to disk.

If you wish to place it somewhere else -- e.g. my pictures etc -- then you'll just need to use one of the other storage folders. See the sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597). Note that to access the pictures library you need to add that capability to your  manifest (just a checkbox in the package.appxmanifest editor in VS)

There are many other imaging options too for more complex manipulation of the output file. See the [imaging sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Imaging-Sample-a2dec2b0) for code.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the most helpful bit of code from the simple imaging sample. It lets you encode to PNG or JPG rather than just dumping the canvas data.

```
Helpers.getFileFromSavePickerAsync().then(function (file) {
    filename = file.name;

    switch (file.fileType) {
        case ".jpg":
            encoderId = Imaging.BitmapEncoder.jpegEncoderId;
            break;
        case ".bmp":
            encoderId = Imaging.BitmapEncoder.bmpEncoderId;
            break;
        case ".png":
        default:
            encoderId = Imaging.BitmapEncoder.pngEncoderId;
            break;
    }

    return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
}).then(function (_stream) {
    stream = _stream;

    // BitmapEncoder expects an empty output stream; the user may have selected a
    // pre-existing file.
    stream.size = 0;
    return Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(encoderId, stream);
}).then(function (encoder) {
    var width = id("outputCanvas").width;
    var height = id("outputCanvas").height;
    var outputPixelData = Context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

    encoder.setPixelData(
        Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.rgba8,
        Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.straight,
        width,
        height,
        96, // Horizontal DPI
        96, // Vertical DPI
        outputPixelData.data
        );

    return encoder.flushAsync();
}).then(function () {
    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Saved new file: " + filename, "sample", "status");
    id("buttonSave").disabled = false;
    id("buttonRender").disabled = false;
}).then(null, function (error) {
    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Failed to save file: " + error.message, "sample", "error");
}).done(function () {
    stream && stream.close();
});
```