# Set desktop wallpaper in JavaScript Windows 8 Application

Tags: javascript, windows-8, desktop-wallpaper

Is there any way to set desktop wallpaper from Windows 8 application written in JavaScript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this is not possible.

Your only option is to write the image to the users pictures library (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225951/how-to-save-html5-canvas-as-an-image-file-in-window-8-metro-app/12230195#12230195)), and then allow the user to pick that as their desktop wallpaper.