# How to save canvas as image file in picture library WP app with HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

Now in my WP 8.1 app using HTML5/CSS/Js, I can draw a canvas. I would like to save this canvas as jpg file in my phone, like `canvas.toDataURL()` or any similar way.

So how can I do it ? 
Thanks for read.

Comment: I think that's impossible due to security reasons.

Comment: maybe this answer could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12230195/1861097?

Comment: Clearified the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 function(canvas,imgfilename ) {
      var fileStream, imgData;
      var Imaging = Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
      var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;
      localFolder.createFileAsync(imgfilename, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting).then(function(file) {
           return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
      }).then(function(stream) {
           fileStream = stream;
           var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
           imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctrl.canvas.width, ctrl.canvas.height);
           return Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(Imaging.BitmapEncoder.jpegEncoderId, stream);
      }).then(function(encoder) {
           encoder.setPixelData(Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.rgba8, Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.straight, canvas.width, canvas.height, 96, 96, new Uint8Array(imgData.data));
           return encoder.flushAsync();
      }).done(function() {
           fileStream.close();
      }, function() {});
 }
```

Comment: You don't want "var" in front of imgData on line 10 since you want the imgData variable from the outer scope (not a new one scoped to the inner function).

Also, declaring multiple variables on one line is a bad practice, don't do it.